# WPF TemplateSelector to draw different figures on just one canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have a block of code in my `xaml` that it is repeated several times, each to draw a different predefined figure (rectangle 1,2...n, sellipse1,2...n, etc) programmatically:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyEllipse}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas Width="200" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
      </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Ellipse Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I would like to find a way of having this summarized with a Data/Item `TemplateSelector`, but after trying several approaches i couldn't get it to work.
Any little working example would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can define a datatemplate with a datatype. This is then used to template any instance of that type. You could then have an ellipsevm, a rectanglevm etc and put your datatemplate for each in a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml. Then any time a ellipsevm is presented to ui it's templated into an ellipse and so on. You could also have a style targetting itemscontrol which sets common properties used in several itemscontrols.

Comment: Thanks Andy, could you please elaborate a very simple example of your suggestion, or point me out a good post about this? I am really new to WPF and this sounds a bit too messy yet to me... thanks!